# TensorFlow training with large dataset takes too long

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Yesterday, I have created a pretrained VGG19 with custom head and tried to train it with 60000 images. After more than 12 hours, the training of first epoch didn't complete.
The batch size has been set to 64 and the number of steps per epoch has been set to training_set_size/batch_size.

Below is the code of DataLoader:

```
    IMAGE_CHANNEL = 3

def crop(image, margin):
    return image[margin:-margin, margin:-margin]


def random_rotation(image, angle):
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((0, 0),angle,1)
    rows,cols, _ = image.shape
    new_img = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (cols, rows))
    return new_img


def get_generator(in_gen, should_augment=True):
    weights = None
    if should_augment:
        image_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(fill_mode='reflect',
                                       data_format='channels_last',
                                       brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5])
    else:
        image_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(fill_mode='reflect',
                                       data_format='channels_last',
                                       brightness_range=[1, 1])
    for items in in_gen:
        in_x, in_y = items
        g_x = image_gen.flow(255 * in_x, in_y, batch_size=in_x.shape[0])
        x, y = next(g_x)
        yield x / 255.0, y


class DataLoader:
    def __init__(self, source_filename, dataset_path, image_size, batch_size, training_set_size=0.8, sample_size=None):
        path_dataset = Path(dataset_path)
        path_image_folders = path_dataset / 'images'
        self.data = pd.read_pickle(source_filename)
        if sample_size is not None:
            self.data = self.data[:sample_size]
        self.image_size = image_size
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.training_set_size = training_set_size
        self.steps_per_epoch = int(self.data.shape[0] * training_set_size // batch_size)
        if self.steps_per_epoch == 0: self.steps_per_epoch = 1
        self.validation_steps = int(self.data.shape[0] * (1 - training_set_size)//batch_size)
        if self.validation_steps == 0: self.validation_steps = 1

    def draw_idx(self, i):
        img_path = self.data.iloc[i].image
        img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(str(img_path)))
        # print(img.shape)
        height, width, _ = img.shape
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15), facecolor='w')
        # original image
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        ax.imshow(img / 255.0)
        openness = self.data.iloc[i].Openness
        conscientiousness = self.data.iloc[i].Conscientiousness
        extraversion = self.data.iloc[i].Extraversion
        agreeableness = self.data.iloc[i].Agreeableness
        neuroticism = self.data.iloc[i].Neuroticism
        ax.title.set_text(
            f'O: {openness}, C: {conscientiousness}, E: {extraversion}, A: {agreeableness}, N: {neuroticism}')
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()

    def get_image(self, index, data, should_augment):
        # Read image and appropiate landmarks
        image = cv2.imread(data['image'].values[index])
        h, w, _ = image.shape
        o, c, e, a, n = data[['Openness', 'Conscientiousness', 'Extraversion', 'Agreeableness', 'Neuroticism']].values[
            index]

        should_flip = random.randint(0, 1)
        should_rotate = random.randint(0, 1)
        should_crop = random.randint(0, 1)
        if should_augment:
            if should_flip == 1:
                # print("Image {} flipped".format(data['path'].values[index]))
                image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
            if should_rotate == 1:
                angle = random.randint(-5, 5)
                image = random_rotation(image, angle)
            if should_crop == 1:
                margin = random.randint(1, 10)
                image = crop(image, margin)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (self.image_size, self.image_size))
        return [image, o, c, e, a, n]

    def generator(self, data, should_augment=True):
        while True:
            # Randomize the indices to make an array
            indices_arr = np.random.permutation(data.count()[0])
            for batch in range(0, len(indices_arr), self.batch_size):
                # slice out the current batch according to batch-size
                current_batch = indices_arr[batch:(batch + self.batch_size)]
                # initializing the arrays, x_train and y_train
                x_train = np.empty(
                    [0, self.image_size, self.image_size, IMAGE_CHANNEL], dtype=np.float32)
                y_train = np.empty([0, 5], dtype=np.int32)
                for i in current_batch:
                    # get an image and its corresponding color for an traffic light
                    [image, o, c, e, a, n] = self.get_image(i, data, should_augment)
                    # Appending them to existing batch
                    x_train = np.append(x_train, [image], axis=0)
                    y_train = np.append(y_train, [[o, c, e, a, n]], axis=0)
                    # replace nan values with zeros
                    y_train = np.nan_to_num(y_train)

                yield (x_train, y_train)

    def get_training_and_test_generators(self, should_augment_training=True, should_augment_test=True):
        msk = np.random.rand(len(self.data)) < self.training_set_size
        train = self.data[msk]
        test = self.data[~msk]
        train_gen = self.generator(train, should_augment_training)
        test_gen = self.generator(test, should_augment_test)
        return get_generator(train_gen, should_augment_training), get_generator(test_gen, should_augment_test)


    def show_batch_images_sample(self, images, landmarks, n_rows=3, n_cols=3):
        assert n_rows * n_cols <= self.batch_size, "Number of expected images to display is larger than batch!"
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
        xs, ys = [], []
        count = 1
        for img, y in zip(images, landmarks):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(n_rows, n_cols, count)
            ax.imshow(img)
            h, w, _ = img.shape
            o, c, e, a, n = y
            ax.title.set_text(f'{o}, {c}, {e}, {a}, {n}')
            ax.axis('off')
            if count == n_rows * n_cols:
                break
            count += 1


class CallbackTensorboardImageOutput(Callback):
    def __init__(self, model, generator, log_dir, feed_inputs_display=9):
        # assert ((feed_inputs_display & (feed_inputs_display - 1)) == 0) and feed_inputs_display != 0
        self.generator = generator
        self.model = model
        self.log_dir = log_dir
        self.writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(self.log_dir)
        self.feed_inputs_display = feed_inputs_display
        self.seen = 0

    def plot_to_image(figure):
        """Converts the matplotlib plot specified by 'figure' to a PNG image and
        returns it. The supplied figure is closed and inaccessible after this call."""
        # Save the plot to a PNG in memory.
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
        # Closing the figure prevents it from being displayed directly inside
        # the notebook.
        plt.close(figure)
        buf.seek(0)
        # Convert PNG buffer to TF image
        image = tf.image.decode_png(buf.getvalue(), channels=4)
        # Add the batch dimension
        image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
        return image

    @staticmethod
    def get_loss(gt, predictions):
        return tf.losses.mse(gt, predictions)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.seen += 1
        if self.seen % 1 == 0:
            items = next(self.generator)
            images_to_display = self.feed_inputs_display
            images_per_cell_count = int(math.sqrt(images_to_display))
            # in case of regular model training using generator, an array is passed
            if not isinstance(items, dict):
                frames_arr, ocean_scores = items
                # Take just 1st sample from batch
                batch_size = frames_arr.shape[0]

                if images_to_display > batch_size:
                    images_to_display = batch_size
                frames_arr = frames_arr[0:images_to_display]
                ocean_scores = ocean_scores[0:images_to_display]

                y_pred = self.model.predict(frames_arr)
            # in case of adversarial training, a dictionary is passed
            else:
                batch_size = items['feature'].shape[0]
                if images_to_display > batch_size:
                    images_to_display = batch_size
                # items['feature'] = items['feature'][0:images_to_display]
                # landmarks = items['label'][0:images_to_display]
                frames_arr = items['feature']
                landmarks = items['label']
                y_pred = self.model.predict(items)

            figure = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
            for i in range(images_to_display):
                image_current = frames_arr[i]
                y_prediction_current = y_pred[i]
                y_gt_current = ocean_scores[i]
                lbl_prediction = 'plot/img/{}'.format(i)
                ax = plt.subplot(images_per_cell_count, images_per_cell_count, i + 1, title=lbl_prediction)
                ax.imshow(image_current)
                ax.axis('off')

            with self.writer.as_default():
                tf.summary.image("Training Data", CallbackTensorboardImageOutput.plot_to_image(figure), step=self.seen)
```

Below is the definition of the network architecture and the call of fit_generator function:

```
data_loader = dataloader.DataLoader('dataset.pkl', '/home/niko/data/PsychoFlickr', 224, 64)
train_gen, test_gen = data_loader.get_training_and_test_generators()

pre_trained_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(input_shape=(data_loader.image_size, data_loader.image_size, dataloader.IMAGE_CHANNEL), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
x = pre_trained_model.output
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)

# Add a fully connected layer with 256 hidden units and ReLU activation
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, name='regresion_output')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Activation('linear')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(pre_trained_model.input, x)
print(model.summary())
log_dir = "logs/{}".format(model_name)
model_filename = "saved-models/{}.h5".format(model_name)
cb_tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)
callback_save_images = dataloader.CallbackTensorboardImageOutput(model, test_gen, log_dir)
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(model_filename, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
lr = 1e-3
opt = tf.optimizers.Adam(lr=lr)
model.compile(loss=loss_mse, optimizer=opt, metrics=[loss_mse])
history = model.fit_generator(
                train_gen,
                validation_data=test_gen,
                steps_per_epoch=data_loader.steps_per_epoch,
                epochs=20,
                validation_steps=data_loader.validation_steps,
                verbose=2,
                use_multiprocessing=True,
                callbacks=[checkpoint, callback_save_images, cb_tensorboard]
            )
```

When I tried to run the same procedure with small sample data (200 records), everything seemed to work fine. On the dataset of 60000 records, however, after more than 12 hours the training of 1st epoch hasn't completed.

The training is performed on NVIDIA RTX2080Ti.

I would be thankful if anyone suggested what has to be modified or in general configured in order to train the network on reasonable time.

Comment: Have you tried using ImageDataGenerator?

Comment: @AdrianNegru if you look closely, in the get_generator() he uses ImageDataGenerator

Comment: @AdrianNegru, I pasted the whole class and function that are used in the project in order to make it clearer.